# libpq only inserts first character in string column

Tags: c, postgresql, libpq

So I have this structure in my psql table called `rooms`:

```
                                         Table "public.rooms"
         Column          |          Type          |                     Modifiers
-------------------------+------------------------+----------------------------------------------------
 id                      | integer                | not null default nextval('rooms_id_seq'::regclass)
 room_id                 | integer                |
 room_name               | character varying(100) |
 room_secret             | character varying(255) |
 room_pin                | character varying(100) |
 room_communication_type | character varying(30)  |
Indexes:
    "rooms_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_rooms_on_room_id" UNIQUE, btree (room_id)
    "index_rooms_on_room_name" btree (room_name)
    "index_rooms_on_room_secret" btree (room_secret)
```

And when I try to perform and insert statement from my C program, I get these results:

```
janus_audiobridge=# SELECT * FROM rooms;
 id | room_id | room_name | room_secret | room_pin | room_communication_type
----+---------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------------------------
  1 |  111128 | I         | L           |          | r
  3 |  111129 | C         | c           |          | r
  4 |  111130 | 4         | b           |          | r
  6 |  111131 | 5         | b           |          | r
(4 rows)
```

Notice the `room_name`, `room_secret` and `room_communication_type` only contain 1 character, the origin al data i wanted insert is full sentences of text.

This is my C code:

```
  const char *paramValues[5];
  paramValues[0] = "111131";
  paramValues[1] = room->room_name;
  paramValues[2] = room->room_secret;
  paramValues[3] = room->room_pin;
  paramValues[4] = room->room_communication_type;


  JANUS_LOG(LOG_WARN, "name: %s", paramValues[1]);

  JANUS_LOG(LOG_ERR, "44444\n\n\n");
  PGresult *res = PQexecParams(conn, query,
    5,       /* one param */
    NULL,    /* let the backend deduce param type */
    paramValues,
    NULL,    /* don't need param lengths since text */
    NULL,    /* default to all text params */
    0);      /* ask for text results */
```

When I run the `INSERT` the line `JANUS_LOG` returns correct name, but inserts only the first character.

How can i insert full text into postgres database using libpq?

Thanks!

EDIT: my `query` string:

```
gchar *query = "INSERT INTO rooms(room_id, room_name, room_secret, room_pin, room_communication_type) " 
"VALUES($1::int, $2::char, $3::char, $4::char, $5::char);";
```

Comment: And where is your `PQprepare ()` call ? And what is the definition for `struct room` ?

Comment: I don't use that. Would that fix my problem?

Comment: How does the `query` string look like?

Comment: Updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the cast to `char` in your `INSERT` statement (that is the same as `character(1)`). Then everything should work fine. The cast to `int` is also unnecessary.

You can see what happens with this simple experiment in `psql`:

```
SELECT 'hello'::char;
 bpchar
--------
 h
(1 row)
```

Casting to `character varying` would have worked, but it is unnecessary to cast explicitly, because during `INSERT` an *assignment cast* will be performed anyway.

As [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS) states:

> A cast applied to an unadorned string literal represents the initial
>   assignment of a type to a literal constant value, and so it will succeed
>   for any type (if the contents of the string literal are acceptable input
>   syntax for the data type).

Comment: It worked. By why?! I was following the guidelines. few questions: Is my code secure now(when i removed the cast)?

Comment: Which guidelines?

Comment: In the examples of `PQexecParams` :/

Comment: @IvRRimUm I extended the answer to cover the "why". With that modification, your code looks ok (and safe from SQL injection).

Comment: I guess you mean [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-example.html) sample program. In that example a binary parameter is used, and the comment says: *This is a good safety measure when sending **binary parameters**.*